# storybord in powerpoint 2007

Tags: visual-studio, storyboard, powerpoint

I have MS Office 2007 installed on my PC. I want to use storybord for designing but I am not getting Storybording menu in PowerPoint.

I have searched and found that to use Storybording I have to install visual studio on my PC. 
I have installed Visual Studio 2010. I am still not getting Storybording option on it. 
On my college lab PC, there is PowerPoint 2010 and Visual Studio 2010 is installed and PowerPoint is having storybording manu.

Is any specific adding required for Storybording with PowerPoint 2007 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to install any plugin for Storybording but the reason why you are not getting Storybording menu is because of your visual studio is not having that functionality.

To get Storybording in PowerPoint, you should have following prerequisites :
1) PowerPoint 2007 or later, and 
2) One of the following versions of Microsoft Visual Studio
          Microsoft Visual Studio 11 (2012) Test Professional
          Visual Studio 11 Premium or 
          Visual Studio 11 Ultimate.
Your Visual Studio version is older then these.